# Как заменить класс после нажатия на него

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на класс:

```
<form class="ch" action="" method="post">
        <button class="button orange" type="submit" name="on" onClick="init()">Įjungti serverį</button>
</form>
```

его заменило на:

```
<button class="button grey">Serveris jau įjungtas</button>
```

?
Пробовал:

```
function init() {
    $('.ch').replaceWith("<button class="button grey">Serveris jau įjungtas</button>");
}
```

и

```
$('.ch').click(function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

но почему-то не работает. Нет никакой реакции.
Кнопка запускает процесс:

```
if(isset($_POST['on'])) { 
     $output = shell_exec('bash /var/www/CP/server.sh start');
}
```

Comment: `$('button[class="button orange"]').onclick(function() {
$(this).removeClass("orange");
$(this).addClass('grey');
});`    
я бы сделал так

Comment: Кнопку вместе с form надо заменить или только кнопку внутри?

Comment: @BogdanGudyma, не работает.

Comment: @Doofy, нужно убрать кнопку вместе с формой, а вместо нее вывести просто класс (другой)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<button class="button orange" onclick='init(this)'>server</button>
```

```
function init(e) {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'a.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send('on=');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if(xhr.status == 200) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }
    }

    e.outerHTML = '<button class="button grey">Serveris jau įjungtas</button>';
}
```

<sub>[a.php](http://nowhere)</sub>

```
if(isset($_POST['on'])) { 
    $output = shell_exec('bash /var/www/CP/server.sh start');
    echo $output;
}
```

---

Пример без JavaScript на одном php

```
if(isset($_POST['on'])) {
    $output = shell_exec('bash /var/www/CP/server.sh start');
    echo "<button class='button grey'>Server is jau įjungtas</button>";
} else {
    echo "<form action='' method='POST'>
        <button class='button orange' name='on'>Įjungti serverį</button>
    </form>";
}
```

Comment: Почему то не работает

Comment: @ES., потому что страница обновляется из-за формы после нажатия. Здесь в снипете код работает, потому что страница не обновляется. Нужно идти в сторону запросов

Comment: что конкретно нужно делать с запросами?

Comment: @ES., form отправляет запрос с обновлением странички. Если нужен запрос, можно освободить кнопку от формы и сделать запрос в скрипте. Для чего здесь `form` в скрипте?

Comment: было бы хорошо, не подскажите как внедрить этот php скрипт? Я думаю форма не нужна, по другому я не знаю как реализовать

Comment: @ES., обновил ответ

Comment: Меняется кнопка, но процесс не запускается

Comment: @ES., адрес менял хоть к своему php файлу?

Comment: не заметил, что нужен другой пхп файл. Все работает. Спасибо. А сделать все в одном пхп файле не возможно?

Comment: @ES., php файл серверная часть. Можно сделать на одном php. Если поступает параметр POST, выводим просто кнопку, если не поступает, то выводим кнопку с формой. Так можно избавиться от запроса и обработчика в JavaScript, однако страничка всё-таки обновится

Comment: @ES., добавил пример на одном php, но вариант плохой

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так :

```js
$(function() {
  $("#mybutton ").click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('grey').addClass( "red" )
    $(this).text("Уже включено")
  });
});
```

```css
.grey {
  background: grey;
}
.red {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="button grey" id="mybutton">Выключено</button>
```

Comment: Это не то, что мне нужно. Я хочу заменить форму с классом на другой класс, без формы.

Comment: Вы хотите удалить форму?

Comment: Да, хочу удалить форму с классом и показать другой класс.